# THREE.js on VIVE Headset (JS/Browser/WebGL in Steam)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to develop with THREE.js JavaScript for the VIVE?
Is there a way to run a web browser (Chrome) in full screen mode on VIVE?

I suspect the biggest problem is accessing the controller paddles data?

If it needs Steam for the drivers does Steam have a browser with WebGL/VR integration?

Does the VIVE headset have a camera for AR?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've managed to find some info pertaining to my own inquiry.
This link says WebGL is available on the PS4 but the entire UI is built that way.

http://siliconangle.com/blog/2013/11/20/webgl-graphics-technology-powers-sony-playstation-4-ui/

While this video in a round about way seems to hint the browser Edge is included and running WebGL, which means JavaScript and THREE.js should be also available.

He visits Babylon "JS" which of course confirms the GL part of the question.
http://doc.babylonjs.com/

I'm still not clear on the VIVE integration. I guess it's just a headset in someways, but without a controller driver, which I'm sure is pretty different then a mouse or typical controller (which it probably simulates), it's not the final word on how to "Use VIVE on a console with JavaScript based WebGL?". 
It seems mostly there and once it comes up I'm sure a controller driver will become available on JavaScript.

If anyone can still please add something here, I've not found any information or js src examples for VIVE yet.

Comment: Did you find any more information regarding this?

Comment: No sorry. Wasn't looking since either though.

Answer (score 0):

https://webvr.info/

To get VR running on a web browser, WebVR.info has information regarding how to get up and running. You'll need to run Chromium or Nightly (Firefox), instructions in the link, the features have not yet been deployed to the main browser releases.

To develop a WebVR project there's the javascript A-Frame library that gives you access to three.js

https://aframe.io/

The website contains a lot of great examples and information, and there's a slack channel too which you can join.